# Python: Regex remove substring starting from specific character till any alphabet

Tags: regex

Need a python regex to remove string starting from specific charcater till any aplhabet found.

**Example:**

```
hello world\r\n Processing ....Pass
hello world\r\n Processing .Fail
hello world\r\n Processing ......Error
hello world\r\n Processing ..Fail
hello world\r\n Processing .......<Any string>
```

**Result should be:**

```
hello world\r\n <Any String>
```

here dot after Processing could be any of the number and want to remove Processing ..(n times dot)

Basically I want to remove anything between `\r\n`  to `[A-Z]` pattern but not the pattern

I tried this but it is also removing the pattern.

```
(?s)\\r\\n.*?\.[A-Z][^\w\s]
```

Comment: So from `hello world\r\n Processing ....Pass` you want `hello world\r\n Pass` post replacement?

Comment: here
`hello world\r\n Processing ....<Any String>`
 i want only 
`hello world\r\n <Any String>`

Comment: I doubt it will work in the end, but for now, try `(?s)(\\r\\n).*?\.([A-Z])` and replace with `$1$2` or `\1\2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```bash
(?s)(?<=\\r\\n ).+?(?=[A-Z])
```

and replace with just an empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8AA0ry/1)

**RegEx Break down:**

- `(?s)`: Enable `DOTALL` (single line) mode
- `(?<=\\r\\n )`: Positive lookbehind to assert that we have literal text `\r\n` and a space before the current position
- `.+?`: Match 1+ of any characters
- `(?=[A-Z])`: Lookahead to assert that we have an uppercase letter at the next position